# pagination not working when clicked next button

Tags: cakephp

**Controler**

```
public function search() {

$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

         $this->loadmodel('Usermgmt.User');
        if ($this->request -> isPost()) {
            $this->User->set($this->data);
            $keyword=$this->data['Doctors']['search'];
 //$this->loadmodel('Usermgmt.User');
 $cond=array('OR'=>array("User.username LIKE '%$keyword%'","User.email LIKE '%$keyword%'", "User.first_name LIKE '%$keyword%'", "User.last_name LIKE '%$keyword%'"));




 //$result = $this->paginate('User',array('conditions'=>$cond));
 $result = $this->paginate('User',array($cond));

  $this->set('result', $result);



        }

    }
```

**View**

```
<?php                    
 if (!empty($result)) {   $sl=0;
                            foreach ($result as $row1) {

                            //print_r($row1);
                                $sl++; ?><div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">

        <div style="float:left">

            <?php 
            //echo $row1['id'];
        echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('../files/user/photo/'.$row1 ['User']['photo_dir'].'/'.$row1 ['User']['photo'], array('width' => '180', 'height' => '180')),
                       array('controller'=>'Profiles','action'=>'index',$row1['User']['id']),
                       array('escape' => false));

                        ?>

       </div>
        <div>
        <?php echo h($row1['User']['first_name'])." ".h($row1['User']['last_name'])."</br>";
                                echo h($row1['User']['username'])."</br>";
                                echo h($row1['User']['email'])."</br>";
                                echo h($row1['User']['mobile'])."</br>";
                                echo h($row1['UserGroup']['name'])."</br>";

                                ?></div>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>


                                </div> 

                                <?php }?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('previous'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>

<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next'); ?>                       

<?php }?>
```

here am search the user name or user details like fname, email like and display in view page

here i get output with pagination like 1 2 3 4  only first page displays when i click next page that shows empty pages may be $result getting unset how to solve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The variable result is only *sometimes* set

```
if ($this->request->isPost()) {
    ...
    $result = $this->paginate('User',array($cond));
    $this->set('result', $result);
}
```

The variable result is only set for POST requests - clicking a link is not a post request, therefore the result variable is undefined.

### Ensure you are paginating a GET request

There are several solutions, but the simplest solution to "How to paginate post data" is to not do so. Change your search form to use GET, and ensure the get parameters persist when paginating a request.

At the very least the controller code needs to call `paginate` and `set` for the variables in the view to exist irrespective of how the controller action was reached.